# Append the build flags with extra one when I run `make debug`

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In my case I want to make some debug builds in order to be able to run gdb in my build system:

```
HOST ?=127.0.0.1
PORT ?=7070

CCFLAGS="-std=c++11"
CPP=g++ ${CCFLAGS}
CFLAGS_DBG=" -g -DDEBUG"
TEST_BUILD_PATH="./build/tests"
BUILD_PATH=./build/release
TESTS_SRC_PATH="./tests"
DEBUGER=gdb


# NORMAL TARGETS

build_commandParser: ./src/tools/command_parser.cpp ./src/tools/command_parser.h
    ${CPP} -Wall -g -c ./src/tools/command_parser.cpp -o ${BUILD_PATH}/command_parser.o

build_network: ./src/socket/network.cpp ./src/socket/network.h
    ${CPP} -Wall -g -c ./src/socket/network.cpp -o ${BUILD_PATH}/network.o

build_simpleCommand: ./src/socket/simple_command.cpp ./src/socket/simple_command.h
    ${CPP} -Wall -g -c ./src/socket/simple_command.cpp -o ${BUILD_PATH}/simple_command.o

build: build_simpleCommand build_commandParser build_network ./src/main.cpp
    ${CPP} -pthread -Wall -o ${BUILD_PATH}/server ${BUILD_PATH}/command_parser.o ${BUILD_PATH}/network.o ${BUILD_PATH}/simple_command.o ./src/main.cpp

run: build
    ${BUILD_PATH}/server -h ${HOST} -p ${PORT}

debug: build
    ${DEBUGER} --args ${BUILD_PATH}/server -h ${HOST} -p ${PORT}

clean:
    find ./build ! -name '.gitkeep' -type f -exec rm -f {} + && find ./tests ! -name *.h -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```

As you can see I try to unitlize the `CFLAGS_DBG` variable to pass the debug flags. But as you can see is fails to do so:

```
g++ -pthread -Wall -std=c++11  -c ./src/socket/simple_command.cpp -o ./build/release/simple_command.o
g++ -pthread -Wall -std=c++11  -c ./src/tools/command_parser.cpp -o ./build/release/command_parser.o
g++ -pthread -Wall -std=c++11  -c ./src/socket/network.cpp -o ./build/release/network.o
g++ -pthread -Wall -std=c++11  -o ./build/release/server ./build/release/command_parser.o ./build/release/network.o ./build/release/simple_command.o ./src/main.cpp
```

I also tries this setup:

```
HOST ?=127.0.0.1
PORT ?=7070

CCFLAGS=-pthread -Wall -std=c++11
CCFLAGS_DBG=
CPP=g++
TESTGEN=cxxtestgen
TEST_BUILD_PATH="./build/tests"
BUILD_PATH=./build/release
TESTS_SRC_PATH="./tests"
DEBUGER=gdb

# NORMAL TARGETS

build_commandParser: ./src/tools/command_parser.cpp ./src/tools/command_parser.h
    ${CPP} ${CCFLAGS} ${CCFLAGS_DBG} -c ./src/tools/command_parser.cpp -o ${BUILD_PATH}/command_parser.o

build_network: ./src/socket/network.cpp ./src/socket/network.h
    ${CPP} ${CCFLAGS} ${CCFLAGS_DBG} -c ./src/socket/network.cpp -o ${BUILD_PATH}/network.o

build_simpleCommand: ./src/socket/simple_command.cpp ./src/socket/simple_command.h
    ${CPP} ${CCFLAGS} ${CCFLAGS_DBG} -c ./src/socket/simple_command.cpp -o ${BUILD_PATH}/simple_command.o

build: build_simpleCommand build_commandParser build_network ./src/main.cpp
    ${CPP} ${CCFLAGS} ${CCFLAGS_DBG} -o ${BUILD_PATH}/server ${BUILD_PATH}/command_parser.o ${BUILD_PATH}/network.o ${BUILD_PATH}/simple_command.o ./src/main.cpp

run: build
    ${BUILD_PATH}/server -h ${HOST} -p ${PORT}

.PHONY: debug-flags
debug-flags: CCFLAGS+=-g -DDEBUG

debug: debug-flags build
    ${DEBUGER} --args ${BUILD_PATH}/server -h ${HOST} -p ${PORT}

clean:
    find ./build ! -name '.gitkeep' -type f -exec rm -f {} + && find ./tests ! -name *.h -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```

And I still get the output above. So I want when I build with `make debug` to be able to specify extra flags and set new flags to the linker as well. Do you have any how to do so?

Comment: You have a couple of problems here, but consider this: how do you want to cope with the fact that you can build two different versions of object files such as `command_parser.o`? Suppose a file by that name exists and you then attempt `make debug`; how can Make know whether that file was built with the right flags, and therefore whether it must be rebuilt? One solution is to keep two different build directories for the different versions (e.g. `build/release` and `build/debug`), another is to give them different names (e.g. `command_parser.o` and `command_parser_debug.o`). Any preference?

Comment: The general recommendation that a target should be a file; not always, but that's the general direction. Or, more generally, not verbs but a nouns. This way, make can build an optimal DAG for you. Surprisingly, I couldn't google up a clear guide about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been said in the question comments,
the build process here is a tad unhygienic.
I recommend you change it.

That being said, it is possible to do what you want, quite simply too.
So by way of exposition,
a sketch:

```
$ cat Makefile
flags := normal
debug: flags := overridden

build:
    : $@ flags: ${flags}

debug: build
    : $@ done
```

Here we have a target specific variable `flags`.
`flags` is usually `normal`.
However,
when building `debug` *or any of its dependencies* it becomes `overridden`.

`build` uses `$flags` in an unsurprising way:

```
$ make build
: build flags: normal
```

Surprisingly the value used when you build `build` via `debug` is the target specific one for `debug`:

```
$ make debug
: build flags: overridden
: debug done
```

### Advice

DO NOT DO THIS with your original makefile.
If you do your life will become miserable.
Consider:

1. `make build`
2. edit
3. `make debug`

You will end up with some sort of Frankenbuild — a monster built out of bits.
If you are unlucky it may even link.

Your only guarantee of success will be to do a clean build *every* time.
A classic sign of a terrible makefile.

Comment: So I should consider using a different makefile for debug right? But won't be a maintainance hell if I do that? But I can use the clear before debug as tagret.

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas No, you should keep all build products out of the source tree. One makefile is fine (and to be recommended). That way you can have (say) a `_build/` folder for the output of `make build`, and a `_debug/` folder for the output of `make debug/`. Nice and logical. You don't even need a `make clean` as `rm -rf _debug/` is simpler and, well, cleaner. (The `_` prefix is meant to indicate the folders are temporary and can be rebuilt if you need them again.)